# Python: error with numpy.asarray while coloring a graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors, networkx

I am dealing with a series of graphs which may not be fully connected, e.g. there may be isolated clusters of nodes here and there.

Based on the number of shortest paths that pass through each node, I want to give each node a color coming from `cmap='jet'`.

Code block:

```
#Given my fragmented graph F, count the shortest paths passing through each node:
def num_spaths(F):
            num_spaths = dict.fromkeys(F, 0.0)
            spaths = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(F)
            for source in F:
                for path in spaths[source].values():
                    for node in path[1:]: 
                        num_spaths[node] += 1
            return num_spaths

num_short_paths=num_spaths(F) #Calling the function on F

my_shortest_paths = num_short_paths.values() #Getting the dict values
nodes = F.nodes() #Storing the nodes in F
#Determining the number of colors
n_color = numpy.asarray([my_shortest_paths[n] for n in nodes])
```

If the graph is connected and there are no clusters, I have no problems. If the graph has clusters, `n_color` ends up being a non-continuous array because the fragmented graph has lost some nodes (e.g., going from 0 to N, not all nodes are present in `nodes` if the graph is fragmented).

This produces an error: `IndexError: list index out of range` pointing at the line where `n_color = numpy.asarray([my_shortest_paths[n] for n in nodes])`.

To be more clear about the nodes:

- Non-fragmented graph: `nodes=[0,1,2,3...,N]`
- Fragmented graph: `nodes=[0,2,3,...,N]`

My question: **How can I build my `n_color` taking into account that some nodes may not be present in my graph?** I think this question corresponds to: how can I build a `numpy_array` which is discrete but non-continuous, to be used in conjunction with `cmap`?

**EDIT**

I tried with `n_color=[0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000,35000,40000,45000,50000]`, thus creating some bounds, but then I get this error: `ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `my_shortest_paths` is actually a list and by `my_shortest_paths[n] for n in nodes`, you are using node's name as the index of your list, which caused your problem.

I think you can just use `n_color = numpy.asarray([num_short_paths[n] for n in nodes])` instead.